# Почему z-index не работает?

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, почему в [данном случае](http://spravka-azov.ru/firm.php?id=1174) свойство z-index, присвоенное блоку, в котором выводится карта ОСМ, не перекрывает карту и не отображает внутреннюю тень блока? Спасибо.

Comment: пока не пойму какому именно блоку индекс, но иногда стоит попробовать поставить по больше его, напр. 99999999. Напишите за какой элемент нужно схватиться, `класс` или `id` у него есть?

Comment: Именно тот блок, в котором карта, там же видно его серые границы со скругленными углами, его ид inborder.

Answer (score 1):

Внутренняя тень не будет работать при такой верстке, можете даже не мучатся. Рамку с тенью можете наложить отдельно. Либо целиком, совместив со св-вом pointer-events: none; (которое не везде работает). Либо добавив каждую сторону отдельно

Comment: Простите, почти ничего не понял:( Какая такая верстка, поясните пожалуйста, что "можно даже не мучаться". Как это, наложить рамку отдельно, отдельно от блока? Про св-во pointer-events: none честно говоря не слыхал еще, почитаю. И опять же как это добавить каждую сторону отдельно, через border-right, border-left и т.д., так?

Comment: Можно просто 4 блока с абсолютным позиционированием сделать. Не знаю на сколько это грамотно, конечно.

Comment: Я сделал один блок с тенями поверх с абсолютным поз. и тени стало отображать, другая проблема - карта становится неактивная, когда она под блоком! Думаю, что с 4-мя блоками будет та же беда.

Comment: конечно не будет она кликабельна.) для это я написал про св-во  pointer-events, с помощью которого можно это исправить. Если сделаете 4 блока размерами как тень, то карта будет не кликабельна только по самым краям. У вас тень пикселей 5, не страшно если человек не сможет нажать на карту и самого-самого края

Comment: ух ты, спасибо, попробую завтра! размытие тени всего 2, так что действительно не страшно.

Comment: Даже блоки с абсолютным поз. перекрывает!..